# I am trying to fix a customized 404 error page. If I remove the code that I don't want, will I break the page?

Tags: css, http-status-code-404

I am trying to remove a product category that keeps populating on our 404 error page. I want the page to just be pretty basic and have a search capability without any other functions, especially not the product category widget that site visitors shouldn't even be able to access.
If I just remove this block of code, would that work to remove the column set up on the page or will I end up with an error?

```
.error404.left-sidebar .content-area,
.error404.right-sidebar .content-area {
    width: 100%
}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2 {
    padding: 2.617924em 0;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    border-width: 1px 0;
    margin-bottom: 2.617924em
}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2::after,
.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2::before {
    content: '';
    display: table
}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2::after {
    clear: both
}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2 .widget,
.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2 ul.products li.product {
    margin-bottom: 0
}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2 .col-1 ul.products {
    margin-bottom: 2.2906835em
}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2 .col-1 ul.products li.product {
    width: 45.4545454545%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 9.0909090909%
}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2 .col-1 ul.products li.product:last-child {
    margin-right: 0
}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2 .col-2 {
    padding: 1.618em;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .025)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of looking at the code which you copy / pasted into your question:

```
.error404.left-sidebar .content-area, .error404.right-sidebar .content-area { width:100%}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2 { 
    padding:2.617924em 0;
    border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    border-width:1px 0;
    margin-bottom:2.617924em
}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2::after, .error404 .fourohfour-columns-2::before { 
    content:'';
    display: table
}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2::after { clear:both}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2 .widget,.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2 ul.products li.product { 
    margin-bottom:0
}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2 .col-1 ul.products { margin-bottom: 2.2906835em}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2 .col-1 ul.products li.product {
    width: 45.4545454545%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 9.0909090909%
}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2 .col-1 ul.products li.product:last-child { margin-right:0}

.error404 .fourohfour-columns-2 .col-2 { 
    padding:1.618em;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.025)
}
```

What we are looking at is CSS styling only_ which appears to be for several elements on the page _

So the exact answer to your question is that removing this block of code will not remove the actual column you're trying to get rid of _ It will only remove the styles set for the elements on the page